# How to create windows using windows.h?

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, window

I've been reading tutorials about creating Windows-based apps. Every single one of them tells me to use some kind of library or framework. Now, I understand why the use of libraries and frameworks is the way to go and I understand that, from what I've been told, everyone uses them, so there's nothing wrong with also doing it. But, I really want to get to the bottom of it and find out how windows are created and manipulated from a very low level.

In C/C++ tutorials, I've seen people including the `windows.h` file. What kind of sorcery is going on inside of it? Isn't it just C/C++ code? If it is, then is it possible to create windows without including anything?

Comment: No sorcery, windows.h lets you use the native Win32 API which all other frameworks are based on. Track down a copy of Petzold if you want to learn.

Comment: [MS: Learn  Windows - Create a window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/creating-a-window)

Comment: On MSDN, read [Desktop App User Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/windows-application-ui-development) and in particular [Windows and Messages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/windowing)

Comment: The `windows.h` contains declarations and definitions of macros.  It doesn't create windows.  The operating system has functions you can call to create windows.  You'll need to change your program to an event driven system; or if you only want to draw windows, use a Graphics Framework.

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20030723-00/?p=43073 https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050422-08/?p=35813

Comment: Question isn't really about windows. You are really asking what a header file is and how linking to libraries works. That's stuff of text books.

Comment: The header `"Windows.h"` is named after Windows, the operating system. It is not specifically about creating little windows on the screen. And there is no magic going on inside, just a lot (*a lot*) of declarations for OS-provided functions and data structures.

Comment: *"is it possible to create windows without including anything?"* - Yes, sure. All you need to do is to replicate what the headers are doing for you. Which primarily comes down to declaring functions and defining structures used in the API interface. There's not much use for that, so I'm guessing the question you asked and the problem you want to solve are not the same thing.

Comment: Actually, most people use *raw win32* without any external libraries which are really outdated. Especially when with the new WinUI3

Comment: There's nothing *"raw"* about WinUI 3. It's not just an insanely complex windowing system, it's a full-blown framework of unbounded proportions. And, obviously, it relies on **external** libraries, that just happen to be deployed through Microsoft Store (if you choose to). This isn't "System XAML" anymore, where you could argue that no external libraries were required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Header files (including windows.h) are just lists of things that already exist. For example `stdio.h` has a line something like this (but probably decorated with all sorts of compiler-specific fiddly bits):

```
int printf(const char *fmt, ...);
```

which (and you probably already know this if you have written much code!) tells the compiler **that there is** a function called `printf` which has a `const char*` first argument and then variable arguments after that, and returns `int`.

It does not say what the function does. It does not say where the function is or how it works.

This is exactly the same as when you use a header file (or don't use one) in your own program with more than one source file. The operating system headers are no different from your own headers, except they're a lot bigger.

After each source file is compiled, the *linker* takes all the compiled source files (object files) and possibly also library files. On Windows you have a bunch of library files from the Windows operating system. If you use the function `CreateWindowA` (that's what `CreateWindow` is actually called) the linker looks in all the object files and library files to see where it is defined, and it finds it in `user32.lib`. If you are using Visual Studio then `user32.lib` was added automatically. If you are using something else then maybe you had to add it yourself.

`user32.lib` isn't a real library file, though. It's a Windows thing called an *import library* which means the code is actually in a DLL and the .lib file just has signposts to the DLL. So what ends up happening is the program doesn't have the code for `CreateWindowA`, but it does have a note saying that when loading the program, look in `user32.dll` to find `CreateWindowA`.

When the operating system loads your program it also loads all the DLLs your program uses, such as `user32.dll`.

Okay so what's the code in `user32.dll`? There is a bunch of C code and eventually it gets to something called a *system call* instruction, which is a CPU instruction that tells the CPU to stop running the program, go and tell the operating system to do something with operating system permissions. You can't write a syscall instruction in C or C++, so this part is written in assembly code or inline assembly code. The operating system gets the request and goes and does whatever it needs to do to make a window.

(Yes, you could write one in your program with assembly code, but do note that the instructions needed are different in each Windows version, which is why they're in a DLL - so it's best not to, if you want your program to actually work)

Answer (score 4):

### TL;DR: Your program asks Windows to create a window for it

The Windows.h header contains definitions to allow a C or C++ program to easily interact with the Win32 API.  The Win32 API is the primary API that Windows provides to allow programs to request services and information from the underlying operating system.  It provides services for lots of things; from window management to memory allocation to device enumeration to file handling.  Every program running on Windows is running on top of the Win32 API, whether you use it directly or indirectly (via a programming language's standard library, for example).  When your code "creates a window" using the Win32 API, what you're really doing is asking the Windows operating system to create a window on your behalf.

### But why?

Drawing a window on a screen and providing input to it requires interacting with several different components.  Back in the old days (and even today, in embedded systems) that wasn't that big of a deal.  You wrote your program targeting a specific model of computer, and so you knew exactly what hardware it had and how to manage it.  Plop some data in memory here, poke a register there, and bam, an image appears on the screen.

That's not sufficient anymore.  PCs are incredibly modular, and every system is different.  Different CPUs, different GPUs, different mice, etc, and we expect that our programs will run on any of them.  Correctly managing and controlling all of that different hardware is a huge task.  Never mind the fact that multiple programs are vying for simultaneous control of the same underlying hardware.  You need some sort of central management system that knows exactly what hardware exists and that can mediate the requests from multiple programs to allow them to safely and efficiently share that hardware.  That's the service that Windows (and other modern operating systems) provides.

### OK, but how does Windows create a window?

Even Windows likely doesn't know.  It keeps track of where every window is on the screen, and figures out which ones are on top of others, and figures out which window the mouse was over when it clicked just now, and it will eventually turn all of that information into an image to be drawn on the screen.  Even from Windows' perspective though, all of that information is just data in memory.  How that data got there or what will be done with it is determined by specialized hardware driver programs.  Some of those ship alongside the Windows OS (i.e. the USB mouse driver) while some come from third-parties (i.e. an nVidia GPU driver).  Those drivers are what are ultimately responsible for controlling each piece of hardware in your system.  The Mouse driver will tell Windows where the mouse just clicked, and the GPU driver will tell the GPU what to draw on the screen.